# What type of batteries are these?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

So, I can get these batteries *very* cheap - less than $2 a piece.  However, I have no real idea how to use them.  (I intend to power a robot with them if I can.)  So this begs the question: what *kind* of batteries are they?  Are there commercially available chargers, or is this some kind of specialty unit?

Is it possible to (safely) build your own circuit around these?  I feel almost like this is a little off topic, but honestly I don't know where else to ask this question, as I don't know where to start.

Thank you kindly.

[image]
**Edit:** I don't know how much it means, but the were dumped en mass and they have a self-test function on them... some of them are even full (varies quite a bit.)

Comment: What does the datasheet for the battery say?  What does the man, who sells you these batteries for $2 say?  That's where you should ask this kind of question.

Comment: It's a recycling center.  No datasheets... although I could look them up, *duh.*

Comment: Maybe they are all dead. That's a good reason for them to be in a recycling center.

Comment: Guys, don't encourage people to buy batteries from recycling companies. These companies sell a lot of batteries to not responsible people who just throw them away if they are not working. Lithium is very hazardous substance. These batteries should be recycled, not sold to random people.

Comment: @Kamil: I've thought about it, and you're right. It's one thing to tear a battery pack apart, recycle the electronics, test the individual cells, and then sell them off as "refurbished", and quite another to outright sell people junk.

Comment: Maybe they're mostly being sold to those who "recycle" them into illegal drugs.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany  Do you mean [Lithium-based psychiatric medication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_%28medication%29#Medical_uses)?

Comment: @NickAlexeev Li extracted from batteries is an ingredient in crystal meth, unfortunately.

Comment: *I fear those who have a moral compunction to selling junk have access to resources others do not.*  I make minimum wage+some.  Put me on social security or raise minimum wage if you don't like me buying junk - wage slaves like me (can) come financially relatively ahead with a moderate amount of skill. My $120 [coffee maker](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2478/links-in-comments) was $2 bucks (clogged).  My Linux box was $15 bucks (PSU fan).  Depends on how sales are treated, really, if it's ethical or not - pricing on the very edge of risk *is* unethical.

Comment: Maybe we should all tone back the moral done pointing...

Comment: @user1833028 It is nothing wrong in buying junk in general. If you can do something useful with junk and you are know what are you doing - thats good! This is real recycling. Awesome. But the problem is that you didn't even knew that LiMnO2 battery is not rechargeable battery and you wanted to buy it.

Comment: Rest assured, I will not let any batteries into the regular trash stream.  And I doubt I know anyone who makes illegal drugs!

Answer (score 5):

Bottom one is single use (**not rechargeable!**) battery for heart defibrillator.

These are sold for 2$ price because it's easier to sell them than recycle.

Recycling cost money, so they sell them on ebay or elsewhere to avoid responsibility. Someone buys them and at some point throw them away or... pay money for recycling to company that maybe will sell same battery again.

**Don't buy batteries from recycling companies. Don't let this proceder continue and grow.**

Lithium is hazardous substance and these bastards should recycle batteries, not sell them to random people after someone (or government) paid for recycling them.

Comment: It seems like somebody was at least *trying* to recycle them but the recycling company had their own ideas what that meant.

Comment: Anyway, my point is, how does one recycle a battery if the center you take them to just sells them for $2 to others?

Comment: I think many batteries supposed to be properly recycled just end on "regular garbage" after one or more "resell cycles" like this.

Comment: I could argue the center didn't make too much note of the fact they even had them - they let you rummage - but you have a point.  *I* would just return them (for free) if they don't work.  I'm kind of surprised this doesn't' seem to be regulated, now that you mention it :/

Comment: Actually @Kamil, do you think it is unethical for me to contribute to this practice by buying?  Ironically, the fact I am responsible enough to care means that it becomes more likely for people who *don't* care very much to buy them if I don't..

Comment: @user1833028 Regulations sometimes don't work as they should. For example - as far I know - battery cells with less than 14g of lithium per cell are not hazardous waste. 1 battery with 15g lithium is hazardous waste, but 100 batteries with 13g of lithium each are not hazardous according to US law.

Comment: This sort of thing is a problem in criminal justice, too.. punishments can be very harsh, very lenient, or utterly inconsistent from spot to spot... ahh, just a tangent.

Comment: @user1833028 I don't want to judge you. I just want to say that this proceder is bad and **people who sell stuff like this are very irresponsible**. This is not dumb ecology talking. This is freakin lithium dude. Few mechanically damaged lithium batteries may erradicate whole fish population in small lake.

Answer (score 3):

They are proprietary battery packs, most likely for a single model or range of models of laptops or similar. They will consist of multiple battery cells in series and/or parallel,  heat sensor,  eeprom, and ic (s) for monitoring battery health and state.

With some effort and multiple of the same type including one to sacrifice open you can easily reverse engineer them. But likely they are dead or near dead for reasonable high voltage and amperage usage in a robotics setting...

Comment: I agree with your answer, you missed one fact. Bottom battery on photo is LiMn02 (not rechargeable). However top one might be LiIon, I can't see text clearly.

Comment: While I appreciate the effort of answering the question... I would never encourage a random guy on the internet to open them up. Most of the time Li batteries just splutter a bit when exposed to humidity, but I've seen a few launch a fireball out of it's edges. Lithium is highly reactive, best to dispose of the batteries at a recycling plant (where he oddly bought them) than to try and reuse them.